# Macro that searches word for a word and creates a table

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

Hi I have this Word macro that should scan a word document, find the word Command and then convert that word to a table, with the command in column one and the result in column 2. What have  i done wrong?

```
Sub Search()
Dim IsFound As Boolean
IsFound = True

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Command:"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

While IsFound
 Selection.ConvertToTable Separator:=wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator, _
NumColumns:=2, NumRows:=8, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
With Selection.Tables(1)
    .Style = "Table Grid"
    .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
    .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
    .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
IsFound = Selection.Find.Execute

End With
Wend
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What does it not do, exactly? What goes wrong? Are there any error messages? Please [edit that information int your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1338555/edit). Thanks :)

Comment: The first iteration in `While IsFound` starts before the first `Find.Execute`... execute `Find.Execute` immediately before `While IsFound` additionally.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am pretty new at creating macros. As you can see. It doesn't find the word command and doesn't convert that text into a 2 column 7 row table. This method or property is  not available  because object i empty 4605. it wasn't to select something manually, but i the selection find was doing that

Comment: Avoid of using Selection object. Move cursor to the start of text and search "from current position". After next occurence of the word `Command` found, select all the fragment which needs to transformed to the table form. Then move the cursor unter the created table and repeat search. Do it until the search fails (not found).

Answer (score 0):

Try this... hope it helps.

```
Sub Search()
Selection.HomeKey Word.WdUnits.wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
  .Text = "Command:"
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Format = False
  .Execute
Do While .Found
    Selection.ConvertToTable Separator:=wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator, _
        NumColumns:=2, NumRows:=8, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        .Style = "Table Grid"
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
        .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
    End With
    Selection.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
    .Execute
Loop
End With
End Sub
```